# Spring Boot : order of instantiation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How Spring decided which class to take instantiate first  ?
Does abstract classes precedes rest ?

```
public abstract class GenericService {
    @Autowired
    SoaConfig soaConfig;
    public GenericService() {
        System.out.println("----- hi-----"+soaConfig);
    }
}

public class SoaConfig  {
    SoaConfig() {
        System.out.println("\n---- soa config ----");
    }
}

public class SSI extends GenericService {
   public SSI() {
     System.out.println("---- SSI ----");
   }
}
```

Output is

```
----- hi-----null
---- SSI ----

---- soa config ----
```

How i can make, my dependency should always instantiate first  ?
I tried, `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE), @Priority` but no luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract classes are not beans in Spring.  Only `SSI` and `SoaConfig` classes may be beans.  So you can only specify the order for them.

> Does abstract classes precedes rest ?

Indeed and this doesn't have any relation with Spring.  It is a Java concept.
A constructor **has to** invoke as first statement its parent constructor.
So as `SSI` is instantiated by Spring, `GenericService` constructor is first invoked.

About your issue, you have to be aware that for a bean which the class has a no arg constructor, injection on fields or setters occurs after constructor instantiation.  So here :

```
    System.out.println("----- hi-----"+soaConfig);
```

`soaConfig` can only be `null`.

As alternative to `@Order` or `@Priority`, you could declare the `SoaConfig` 
 dependency required as parameter in the constructor. 
In this way, Spring will inject the `SoaConfig` bean directly in the constructor invocation.

```
public abstract class GenericService {   
    SoaConfig soaConfig;
    public GenericService(SoaConfig soaConfig) {
       System.out.println("----- hi-----"+soaConfig);
    }
}

public class SSI extends GenericService {
   public SSI(SoaConfig soaConfig) {
      super(soaConfig);
      System.out.println("---- SSI ----");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the Autowired object as a parameter for the constructor:

```
public abstract class GenericService {
    @Autowired
    public GenericService(SoaConfig soaConfig) {
        System.out.println("----- hi-----"+soaConfig);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SoaConfig  {
    SoaConfig() {
        System.out.println("\n---- soa config ----");
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SSI extends GenericService {
   public SSI(SoapConfig soapConfig) {
     System.out.println("---- SSI ----");
   }
}
```